# change .php extension to custom (.asp)

Tags: .htaccess

i have some php files on my site like
example.com/WEB/file.php
but i dont want others to see that site is made on php

so can  i show same content but extension to be .aspx

i tried this but dont work 
when i visit  example.com/WEB/file.php it redirect to example.com/file.asp

```
Options +MultiViews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 

# Chnage .php extension to .asp
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.php  
 RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php $1.aspx [R=301,L]  

# Chnage .html extension to .asp
 RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.html  
 RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1.aspx [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

"[R=301,L]" means redirect with code 301. It seems you don't want a redirect but instead a rewrite, so do

```
# Change .asp extension to .php

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (.*)\.asp  
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.asp $1.php [PT]
```

[PT] is passthrough, which means the url goes through any rules again, from the top, in its rewritten format.

Details on flags like [PT] are on manual page: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: when i visit  example.com/WEB/file.asp

i get 
The requested URL /file.asp was not found on this server.

Comment: @ArlindPajaziti you wrote "i dont want others to see that site is made on asp net", so you should be using file.php urls (which would be file.asp on disk), right?

Comment: wrongly typed, i corrected, so my site is on .php  and i dont want others to see .php

Comment: ah. well, that's vice versa then. changed my answer.